# How to make ping URL without www?

Tags: ping, icmp

I want to ping to this URL:
https://api.mercadopago.com/checkout/preferences?access_token=
but it's not working.

How would I ping the URL shown?

Answer (score 0):

Just type: `ping api.mercadopago.com`

However, some servers have their firewall set up to prevent [ICMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Control_Message_Protocol) (ping) requests.

It seems to be the case with this MercadoPago server, that's why you can't ping it.

Comment: Access to https://api.mercadopago.com/ is forbidden even from browser: 403 Forbidden - You don't have permission to access the URL on this server. . Ping to this site goes to Time out.